# Creating CSP AAD and change user password

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

**Background**

I create an CSP Customer (Azure Active Directory) through the REST API and then connect this customer to my Azure Stack. In order to automatically connect their account with the Azure Stack I need to grant this from both sides, customer account and my Stack.

Hence, I need to use the customers password to login and grant Azure Stack access from the customers side.

**Problem**

I create a CSP customer (password cannot be set during creation) and the password is returned when successful (using the CSP REST API). The password is automatically set to be changed at next login. Hence, I cannot use the returned password programatically until manually setting a new password (not wanted!).

Is there a way to change the customer password using the REST API? Either through CSP or Graph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible to change the password for the newly created CSP customer by using the CSP REST API. However, it must be accessed with both API + User credentials in order to be able to change the password.

Change password REST API request:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/reset-user-password-for-a-customer

> Credentials as described in Partner Center authentication. This
>   scenario supports authentication with App+User credentials only.